# AddYear method doesn't work as excpected

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to add years to a `DateTime` variable, but for some reason this function doesn't affect at all..

This is my code:

```
DateTime dtCmp = new DateTime(calendarBirthDay.Value.Year, calendarBirthDay.Value.Month, calendarBirthDay.Value.Day);
dtCmp.AddYears(DateTime.Now.Year - calendarBirthDay.Value.Year);
```

I tried even something trivial likewise :

```
dtCmp.AddYears(1);
```

and this is doesn't work yet..

Comment: What effect do you expect actually? Changing `dtCmp`? `DateTime` is an immutable type. You can't change it. Even if you think you change it, you actually create a new instance.

Comment: If you really want to understand what happens when you call AddYears you should look at the source code of AddMonths (called internally by AddYears) [See ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,02ff6ea643eb71e8,references)

Comment: The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly says: *This method **does not change** the value of this DateTime object. Instead, it **returns a new DateTime** object whose value is the result of this operation.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store it back to the variable to reflect the change.

```
dtCmp = dtCmp.AddYears(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

AddYears method returns a new instance of DateTime object because DateTime is a struct. You need to store returned value into itself to increase old value:

```
dtCmp = dtCmp.AddYears(1)
```